# Drop firt n elements of a list if less than 2 in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Drop the first n  elements of a list if less than 2 . Error says " no instance for (showa0) arising from use of 'print'..." I never understand Haskell error massages

```
func [] _  _ = []
func (x:xs) counter n 
       |  x > 2 && counter < n = x :func xs counter limit 
       | otherwise = func xs (counter+1) limit 

main = do 
 print $  func [3,1,4,2,1] 0 2
 -- expectet output is [3,4,1]
```

Comment: Please show your real code. `counetr` is non-existent. Give an SSCCE.

Comment: @not-rightfold I don't understand what you mean 'counter' doesn't exist, I assumed it is a variable.

Comment: Eh, `counetr`, not `counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should remove the compile errors:

```
func [] _  _ = []
func (x:xs) counter n 
       |  x > 2 && counter < n = x :(func xs counter n )
       | otherwise = func xs (counter+1) n

main = do 
 print $  func [3,1,4,2,1] 0 2
```

You have defined new variable `limit` instead of `n`. Also you may want to explore library functions like `take` and `drop`.